# How do I automatically run an application when the system starts?

Tags: c#, windows

how to make application startup without using startup folder , is there any way instead of Windows Service ?

Comment: Please bear in mind that any of these mechanisms will impact the user login experience in terms of performance, and that your code won't ever get run if a user just locks their machine at the end of the day - consider using Task Scheduler.

Comment: However the questions is probably about how to automate adding application as a startup item, and not for scheduling running of the application. Many applications startup on logon and depending on this application - it might be a right way to go. Naturally adding many apps to startup will impact logon. It's possible to manually delay startup but it will be slightly more cumbersome and might not even be required.

Comment: The startup folder is actually a good idea. You should not dismiss it this easily. It allows users to easily manage which applications start with the system.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create key in the registry:

```
RegistryKey app = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run", true);
app.SetValue("name", Application.ExecutablePath.ToString());
```

This will add it to startup apps for current user.

Answer (score 4):

Registry entry could do this.

The Registry keys most often involved with startup have the word "Run" in them somewhere. They are listed below using the abbreviation HKLM for the major key (or "hive") called "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE" and HKCU for for the hive "HKEY_CURRENT_USER"

HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run
HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunOnce
HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunServices
HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunServicesOnce
HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run
HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunOnce
HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunOnceEx

You probably have several items in some of them already.
Just add additional items there.

Here is how HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run  might look in Regedit (Run-> type "regedit" -> Enter). The right pane shows a number of programs that will run when this system is started.
[image]

Hope this helps :-)

Answer (score 0):

put it to registry like "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run"

Answer (score 0):

If you wanna set your application start just for specific user, use this:
`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run`

and if u want to run in all users use thisone:
`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run`